# How to run same test on multiple android devices with different application

Tags: android, selenium, appium

I have multiple real devices and want to start on each device different application. There is a way to run this in parallel ?
How should I setup me setup function ?

Thanks

Comment: Check seleniumgrid with appium where you can define your device and app

Answer (score 0):

Launch 2 servers with different `--port`, `--bootstrap-port` and `--udid` values and target those servers with your test scripts by adjusting the appium URL to use the same port as what you specified to `--port`. For example:

`~/Git/appium $ node . --port 4723 --bootstrap-port 4823 --udid 12345abcd`

`~/Git/appium $ node . --port 4724 --bootstrap-port 4824 --udid abcd54321`

`--udid / -U` takes in the ID of your Android device as seen from command `adb devices`

Your scripts would in this case need to target either `http://localhost:4723/wd/hub` or `http://localhost:4724/wd/hub` depending on if you want to automate the device with id `12345abcd` or `abcd54321`

Comment: Thanks @Domestus, my question is about apk's, how can I tell my setup() to take first time app 1 and second time app 2 ?

Comment: Could you share your current setup() ? You will want to have different set of desired capabilities for each webdriver session to target different apps.